# Import a Table from Soccer or Hockey to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: import, google-sheets

I have some problems to import a table to my Google Spreadsheet -> For a Sample I use this URL:
https://www.sofascore.com/de/turnier/93/13507/tabelle/tabellen/embed

"importurl" is not right for sofascore and I use

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.sofascore.com/de/turnier/93/13507/tabelle/tabellen/embed"; "//div[@class='tab-content js-standings-tables-part-panels']")
```

My problem is that all the data in a cell is, I need every value in an extra cell, here a photo about my Problem:

[image: image of spreadsheet]

Can anybody  fix this issue?